# Will I damage my car if I don't fix evaporator core leak?

Tags: ford, ac, focus

Pretty sure my evaporator core has a leak, super expensive to fix. Can I just charge it 3 times a year or so? Is this going to damage my car?

Comment: In the US, at least, R134a costs about $20 for a 12ounce can - so you're going to drain $60 into the atmosphere each year (plus the cost of killing planet Earth, etc..). I'd suggest taking it to a reputable garage (not many advertise as 'disreputable', of course), and get them to find the leak with some UV dye; it may be a quick fix.

Comment: R134a it toxic to humans in higher concentrations, I don't think it is a good idea to continually charge it when the R134a is leaking into the passenger cabin.

Answer (score 4):

A/C systems that are run low on refrigerant fail faster than those that are kept full. This is because the refrigerant circulates to oil that lubricates the compressor. An un-lubricated compressor will wear out. So just after filling the oil will circulate normally but as the refrigerant level drops so will compressor lubrication.

Also it is less than ideal to leak R134a refrigerant into the atmosphere; it is a greenhouse gas.